# Unable to pass Header Authorization in JMeter. Facing unauthorizedError

Tags: jmeter

I'm running Performance test in JMeter where I have to pass Authorization details using Header Manager.

Here is my code:

```
String headerName = "Authorization";
String headerValue = "Basic MyKey MyValue";

Header bcHeader = new Header(headerName,headerValue);
HeaderManager hm = new HeaderManager();
hm.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
hm.add(bcHeader);
hm.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
hm.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
```

And I'm facing `UnAuthorized error`.

Please let me know if there is another way to write the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) in order to bypass [Basic HTTP Auth](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) challenge.

However if you're going to manually construct [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header be aware that it should have the following form

- Name: `Authorization`
- Value: `Basic`

After `Basic` you need to provide username and password separated by colon and encoded into [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). So if your username is `MyKey` and password is `MyValue` you should encode the string `MyKey:MyValue` and add the result to the header so it would look like:

```
Basic TXlLZXk6TXlWYWx1ZQ==
```

When it comes to Java code it would be something like:

```
String headerName = "Authorization";
String username = "MyKey";
String password = "MyValue";
Header bcHeader = new Header(headerName,
        "Basic " +
                Base64.encodeBase64String((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
HeaderManager hm = new HeaderManager();
hm.add(bcHeader);
hm.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
hm.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
hm.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("header_manager_title"));
hm.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
hm.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());
```

Comment: I tried this but still gets the same error. UnAuthorized. In my case, "MyValue" is already base64 encoded. Is there any other alternative or need to set any other properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are getting  authorization header value somewhere in your response you can extract and dynamic values and apply correlations to the script.
2. Here is what you have to do. Extract Authorization header value using [regular expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and store it in a jmeter variable lets assuem you have saved it as `Auth` .
3. Add a [header manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) (Right click on thread group -->config element--> Header manager) according to jmeter scoping rules.
4. Use ${variablename} and replace the hard coded header value with ${variablename} ,as we saved it in Auth variable you can use `${Auth}`.
5. You can add headers to header manager click on add and give header name and value as shown below

i'm getting authorization value in request 1's reponse as shown below

[image]

so to extract this add a [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to the same request (request 1) as shown below.

[image]

Now we can use ${Auth} in header manager , add [header manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to request 2 and give header name and values as shown below

[image]

you can see in the results authorization has passed  its value
[image]

For more information on Extracting variables please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Let me know if it helps